# Nenhum bean corresponde ao ponto de injeção CDI

Tags: java, cdi

Estou querendo implementar CDI. Porém quando uso a anotação @Inject sou notificado com esse aviso

"Nenhum bean corresponde ao ponto de injeção"

Linha do código que sou notificado

```
@Inject private LancamentoDadosDao lancamentoDadosDao;
```

Classe DAO

```
    @Component
    @RequestScoped
    public class LancamentoDadosDao {

        private Session session;
        private Result result;

        public LancamentoDadosDao(Session session, Result result) {
            this.session = session;
            this.result = result;
        }
}
```

O que pode estar ocorrendo para esse warning aparecer ?

Answer (score 1):

Para ser usada com CDI sua classe precisa ter um construtor sem parâmetros ou o seu construtor com parâmetros deve ser anotado com @Inject (mas ai garanta que os parâmetros serão injetados corretamente).